# Reversing components in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
Tl={{a, 3, b}, {c, 6, d}, {e, 9, f}, {g, 5, h}}
```

I really want to reverse specific elements of this list such that I get the following:

```
lT= {{b,5, a}, {d, 9, c}, {f, 6, e}, {h, 3, g}}
```

The best I could do is:

```
Reverse /@ tl

(* output: {{b, 3, a}, {d, 6, c}, {f, 9, e}, {h, 5, g}} *)
```

Any suggestions? The method should hold for any even number (say `N`)  of sublists (consisting of 3 elements) in the original data set. As can be seen, `N=4` for this case.

Comment: `lt=tl;lt[[All,2]]=Reverse@lt[[All,2]]`

Comment: @ciao I also think the first and third elements are reversed

Comment: @PeterRoberge: Yep, missed that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll solve this in two parts to better see what's going on.

(changing variable to t)

```
t = {{a, 3, b}, {c, 6, d}, {e, 9, f}, {g, 5, h}}
```

Part one will create sub-lists of the first and third element of each list:

```
p1 = Map[Reverse, t[[All, {1, 3}]]]

{{b, a}, {d, c}, {f, e}, {h, g}}
```

Part two will reverse the second element:

```
p2 = Reverse [t[[All, 2]]]

{5, 9, 6, 3}
```

Then put it all back together:

```
Transpose[{p1[[All, 1]], p2[[All]], p1[[All, 2]]}]

{{b, 5, a}, {d, 9, c}, {f, 6, e}, {h, 3, g}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one-liner:

```
m = {{a, 3, b}, {c, 6, d}, {e, 9, f}, {g, 5, h}}

Reverse /@ Transpose@MapAt[Reverse, Transpose[m], 2]

(* {{b, 5, a}, {d, 9, c}, {f, 6, e}, {h, 3, g}} *)
```

Here's another one:

```
MapThread[Riffle, {m[[All, {3, 1}]], m[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, {2}]]}]
```

And another:

```
Thread[{m[[All, 3]], m[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 2]], m[[All, 1]]}]
```

Also, as suggested by @Kuba, which is shorter yet in the notebook. Unfortunately, the font in the editor doesn't support the superscripted "T" for transposition (it's unicode F3C7), so it doesn't look as nice here. `` is equivalent to `:tr:`.

```
{#3, Reverse@#2, #1} & @@ (m)
```

The challenge remains to make this even shorter.

Comment: Both are good answers!

Answer (score 9):

```
Transpose[{#[[;; , 3]], #[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 2]], #[[;; , 1]]}] &@lt
```

or

```
Transpose[{#3, Reverse[#2], #1}] & @@ Transpose[lt]
```

Comment: Nice use of apply, +1

Comment: This is a beauty!

Comment: @LLlAMnYP thanks, but I still feel like we are missing a shorter solution :)

Comment: `Thread[{#3,Reverse@#2,#1}&@@Transpose@m]` is 5 characters shorter than yours. I don't see a shorter solution... (and that's mostly thanks to syntactic sugar)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Keep in mind you can use :tr: syntax too :)

Comment: @Kuba, what is :tr: syntax? BTW, both `Transpose` can be changed by `Thread`

Comment: @garej It's  `list\[Transpose]` which can be entered by esc-tr-esc.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given and desired lists are:

```
Tl = {{a, 3, b}, {c, 6, d}, {e, 9, f}, {g, 5, h}};
lT = {{b, 5, a}, {d, 9, c}, {f, 6, e}, {h, 3, g}};

Rule @@ MatrixForm /@ {Tl, lT}
```

[image]

1. The second column needs to be reversed (upside down).
2. The first and the third column need to be interchanged.

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
SubsetMap[Reverse,
 SubsetMap[Reverse, #, {1, 3}] & /@ Tl
 , {All, 2}]
```

> {{b, 5, a}, {d, 9, c}, {f, 6, e}, {h, 3, g}}

Comment: The `Join` variant similar to other answers would be: `Transpose@Join[{Tl[[All, 3]]}, {Reverse@Tl[[All, 2]]}, {Tl[[All, 1]]}]`